# Show that in figure bisector of angle intersect at perpendicular

Tags: geometry

The following was asked by a high school student which I could not answer. Please help

In the figure below, show that the bisector of $\angle AEB$ and $\angle AFD$ intersect at perpendicular [image]

Comment: I'm guessing that $ABF, FCD$ must be collinear? Then you just need to trace equal angles.

Comment: Yes they are collinear. Could you give some details please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a better figure:
[image: 1]

Here $ABF, DCF, ADE, BCE$ are collinear, and $PE, PF$ bisects $\angle AEB, \angle AFD$ respectively.

We have:

\begin{align}180^\circ &= \angle BAE + \angle AEB + \angle EBA \\&= \angle BAE + \angle AEB + \angle AFC + \angle BCF\\&=\angle BCF + 2\angle PEB + 2\angle PFC + \angle BCF\end{align}

This shows that $\angle BCF + \angle PEB + \angle PFC = 90^\circ$.

Now consider the quadrilateral $PFCE$ and you will finish the proof:

\begin{align}360^\circ &= \angle PFC + \text{reflex}\angle FCE + \angle CEP + \angle EPF\\
&=\angle PFC + (180^\circ + \angle BCF) + \angle BEP + \angle EPF\\
&=180^\circ + 90^\circ + \angle EPF
\end{align}

giving $\angle EPF = 90^\circ$.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

We claim that $\triangle FHP \cong \triangle FGP$. So $\angle FPG = \angle FPH$. So $\angle FPE = 90^0$.

Now how are they congruent?

$\angle FHP = \angle FAE + \angle AEH$

Also, $\angle FGP = \angle DCE + \angle CEP = \angle FAE + \angle AEH$

So, $\angle FHP = \angle FGP$ and we know $\angle PFH = \angle PFG$.